# In-app guidance for managed package

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api

My goal is to create a walkthrough via in-app guidance for our managed package app.

I created walkthrough of two steps:

1. Prompt in an app page(VF page with lwc components) which redirects to 2.
2. Prompt in installed packages on setup

Unmanaged environment work as expected, but I am failing when trying to create beta package.

I get:
**StepNumber fields in a walkthrough must range from 1 to the number of steps in the walkthrough. When deploying 2 step walkthrough**

or

**These entities are not supported: [Prompt] in your org when creating a walkthrough with first step only.**

1. Is it possible to add walkthroughs/prompts to an app page? will be happy to hear your thoughts.
2. When configuring walkthrough, I can't use app permissions as a restricted measure. Is it possible to configure?
3. How can I test it on managed package?

Answer (score 1):

we are using walkthroughs in all our sample apps (https://github.com/trailheadapps). Definitely you can add a prompt to an app page, look at [this example](https://github.com/trailheadapps/dreamhouse-lwc/blob/main/force-app/main/default/prompts/PropertyExplorer.prompt-meta.xml).

We are also packaging the app in an unlocked package, but I haven't tested how they behave in managed packages.

Not sure about what you mean with the permission question, but there is a [permission set](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customhelp_lex_wt_license.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5#:%7E:text=Select%20the%20Access%20Walkthroughs%20permission,permission%20set%2C%20and%20click%20Assign.) that you can assign to users.

Comment: Hi, thx @Alba Rivas , this is reassuring . How do you test walkthrough in managed package?